# Skype bot card images not showing up

Tags: bots, botframework, skype-bots, microsoft-skype-bot

I am sending this post request and all cards like thumbnail, carousel, hero showing up, but the card image is not showing. I tried many different things but nothing worked yet.

I am creating a bot in python, everything is working fine accept this issue.

These are some links I looked for finding issue. But it seems I am doing everthing correctly. Any help?

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/chat/#navtitle

```
{
'text': 'testinglookssuccessful',
'type': 'message/card.carousel',
'attachments': [{
    'content': {
        'images': [{
            'image': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7c/Seattlenighttimequeenanne.jpg/320px-Seattlenighttimequeenanne.jpg',
            'alt': 'hello'
        }],
        'text': 'cardtext',
        'buttons': [{
            'type': 'imBack',
            'value': 'testingsuccess',
            'title': 'test1'
        }],
        'subtitle': 'herocardsubtitle',
        'title': 'herocardtest'
    },
    'contentType': 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero'
}],
'summary': 'thisismyfirstskypebot'}
```

This is what showing up when I send it to skype through bot.

[screenshot for Skype test bot for hero card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9OpT.png)

Comment: which version of skype do you use?

Comment: I am using https://web.skype.com/en/ beta version to test latest V3 features.

Comment: can you add a few lines of your code?

Comment: `r = requests.post('https://apis.skype.com/v3/conversations/'+sender+'/activities/',headers={"Authorization": "Bearer "+token,"Content-Type":"application/json"},json=payload)
`
The above json is payload,
sender is the id, 
token is the skype token

Comment: Please don't edit your question to put "solved" in the title. Instead, mark the correct answer as accepted (once you can; there is a time limit). Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to tick my own answer as accepted...do you know who can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved :

the issue was with the 'image' key which was mentioned wrongly in the https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/chat/#navtitle documentation. I replaced the 'image' key with 'url' key